# Have Python Code Run Multiple Anaconda Prompt Commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line

Currently, I have to open Anaconda Prompt, activate my python environment and then run my desired anaconda prompt command within the environment. I want to write a python file that would be able to access the anaconda prompt, activate the virtual environment, and run a series of prompts in the environment. Thanks